# Change language of Visual Studio 2017 RC

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have installed Visual Studio 2017 RC, and by default it set language to my system language (Polish) so I was trying to change it to EN but in Options > Environment > International Settings i have only Polish language. There is link to "download more languages", and it redirects to: https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/
And there I can only find language packs for VS 15.
Anyone know where I can find EN language pack for VS 17 RC?

Comment: Hi, thanks for reporting that the download link sends you to the wrong place. I will file a bug for us to take care of that. (Disclosure: I work on Visual Studio at Microsoft)

Comment: @MichaelBraude ha, two years are gone, but that wrong link is still there ;)

Answer (score 271, accepted):

You can only install a language pack at install time in VS 2017 RC. To install RC with a different language:

1. Open the Visual Studio Installer.
2. Find an addition under "Available" and click Install
3. Click on the "Language packs" tab and select a language

[image]

You can have multiple instances of VS 2017 side by side so this shouldn't interfere with your other installation.

Disclosure: I work on Visual Studio at Microsoft.

Comment: The "Language packs" tab aren't available

Comment: You'll only see it on a fresh install. You won't see it on edition you've already installed.

Comment: So I have to uninstall VS2017 first, and install it again, in order to change language?

Comment: Install new instance of VS 17 RC is not the best soution for this problem, I will do it but if you find better way please let us now.

Comment: I was able to install the language pack by re-launching the installer and pick Modify. The Language Packs tab was displayed correctly.

Comment: Note that we will support this scenario in later releases.

Comment: Just an addition, as at least for me it was not clear where to grab the VS Installer (again): as of today with RTM out, on Windows 10, head to Windows Search bar and type `Visual Studio installer` and the desktop app should show up in search results.

Comment: @MichaelBraude Why don't you just set it to English for default? It doesn't make any sense to have it in an other language. I bet at least 95% of all programmers want their IDE to be in English.

Comment: @JonasWirth yeah, you're right. I'm brazilian, and I had to change it to english. Every developer in the team I work for prefers english rather than portuguese.

Comment: This worked. I had to upgade to the latest version before I actually could modify the installation to install a new language.

Comment: @JonasWirth +1. Because every developer searches errors using stack overflow in english. Otherwise nothing comes up

Comment: What you are describing is not there.

Comment: I agree with @JonasWirth. It's much easier to find the options on Visual Studio in English than it is in my own language (Portuguese BR). Changing language settings of VS right now.

Comment: IDE language should be able to be set differently than compiler (errors) language. Integration between IDE and compiler from MS seems to be too deep.

Comment: You have to click modify on your installed version on the Visual Studio Installer. the language tab should be visible

Answer (score 104):

1. Go to **Tools** -> **Options**
2. Select **International Settings** in **Environment** and on the right side of a screen you should see a combo with the list of installed language packages. (so in my case Czech, English and same as on MS Windows )
3. Click on **Ok**

You have to restart Visual Studio to see the change.

If you are polish (and got polish language settings)

1. **Narzędzia** -> **Opcje**
2. **Ustawienia międzynarodowe** in **Środowisko**

Comment: This is the up to date answer. Worked for Russian: Сервис -> Параметры -> Окружение -> Язык.

Comment: It also worked for the German version (I am using VS community, pro users may have a slightly different path to follow; the important part is to get to "Options" or "Optionen"): 

Etras -> Optionen -> Umbegung -> Internationale Einstellungen -> Sprache

Comment: Does not currently work: I also have German, and installed with German and English selected. In the Sprache menu I have the options of German or "sam as Windows" :)

Comment: @SergeRogatch, First menu item was: Средства

Comment: @JoelinGö: I had a similar issue, where I would only see one language out of the 2 installed, and "Same as Windows" wouldn't work. I ended up removing the other language. Maybe you could try removing and reinstalling the language you cannot choose.

Comment: this is what I needed in addition to the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: If this workflow is not working most likely because you can't find a way to install the ILP for other languages on windows, check @Tienhao Shen answer. Briefly... open the visual studio installer, click "modify" under your installed version and choose a new Language pack.

Answer (score 44):

This should solve it:

1. Open the Visual Studio Installer.
2. Click on the Modify Button.
3. Choose the Language Pack tab on top left.
4. Check the language you need and click on the Modify Button at bottom right.

Answer (score 9):

You need reinstall VS.

> **Language Pack Support in Visual Studio 2017 RC**
>
> **Issue**:
>
> This release of Visual Studio supports only a single language pack for the user interface. You cannot install two languages for the user interface in the same instance of Visual Studio. In addition, you must select the language of Visual Studio during the initial install, and cannot change it during Modify.
>
> **Workaround**:
>
> These are known issues that will be fixed in an upcoming release. To change the language in this release, you can uninstall and reinstall Visual Studio.

Reference: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#november-16-2016

Answer (score 6):

In RC2 (and most likely in the final release) you can switch language from inside Visual Studio and you can modify your setup to include other language packs.

> You can now add and remove multiple user interface languages at any
>   time using the Visual Studio installer on the Language Pack tab. You
>   can select the current user interface language among those installed
>   using Tools > Options > International Settings. Source :
>   https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#vside

Answer (score 5):

I didn't find a complete answer here

**Firstly**

You should install your preferred language

1. Open the Visual Studio Installer.
2. In installed products click on **plus** Dropdown menu
3. click edit
4. then click on language packs
5. choose you preferred language and finally click on install

**Secondly**

1. Go to Tools -> Options

   2.Select International Settings in Environment

   3.click on Menu and select you preferred language

   4.Click on Ok

   5.restart visual studio

Answer (score 5):

I solved this just created label on desktop with option/parameter `--locale en-US`

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vs_installer.exe" --locale en-US

Answer (score 4):

You can CHANGE user interface LANGUAGE like this:

Open VS > VS Community > Preferences >
Environment > Visual Style > User Interface language

Woala!!!

Answer (score 2):

For having a language at Visual Studio Ui , basically the language package of that language must be installed during the installation.

> You can not select a **language in options -> environment ->
>   international settings** that didn't installed.

If the language that you want to select in above path is not appearing than you have to modify your visual studio by re-executing installer and selecting Language Packages tab and check your language that you want to have.

[image]

> And than at Visual Studio toolbar just click **Tools --> Options -->**
>   **Environment --> International Settings and than select your language**
>   from dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

Polish-> English (VS on MAC) answer:
When I started a project and was forced to download Visual Studio, went to their page and saw that Microsoft logo I knew there would be problems... And here it is. It occurred difficult to change the language of VS on Mac. My OS is purely English and only because of the fact I downloaded it using a browser with Polish set as a default language I got the wrong version. I had to reinstall the version to the newest and then Visual Studio Community -> Preferences(in the environment section) -> Visual Style-> User Interface Language.

It translates to polish: Visual Studio Community -> Preferencje -> Styl Wizualny w sekcji Środowisko -> Język interfejsu użytkownika -> English.

If you don't see such an option then, as I was, you are forced to upgrade this crappy VS to the newest version.