# Visual studio code installer display language

Tags: visual-studio-code

Does there exist an English Installer for Non-English locale PC?

It seems that the display language of VS Code installer is based on the locale settings. Unlike Visual Studio Installer, the locale settings can be changed using the command line.

E.g.

> *vs_installer.exe --locale en-US*

I have googled and try the command line options above but all in vain. The installer still display with Chinese language.

For some reasons, I can't change my PC locale settings.

BTW, I know how to change display language after installing the VS Code.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40709064/change-language-of-visual-studio-2017-rc) for once

Comment: @Nobody The link is related to Visual Studio not Visual Studio Code. They are different product.

Comment: Maybe this one can help? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/locales

Answer (score 0):

Please add `locale.json` inside your Visual Studio Code folder.

  `{
    "locale":"en"
  }`

For windows, please put locale.json file into this folder. 
`C:/Users/{your-user}/AppData/Roaming/Code/User/`

Comment: The method can only be used after installation. However, I want to know the method during the installation.