# Visual Studio different language text messed up

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When i open the project in VS2017 professional then arabic words messed up.Some files are fine but some files like

```
ÈíÇäÇÊ ÇáãäÔÃÉ
ÈíÇäÇÊ ÇáãäÔÃÉ
```

This is asp.net web forms project. Any one have solution?

Comment: In what encoding are you saving/loading the files?

Comment: Please specify type of file and elaborate more..

Comment: @Richard how can i check?

Comment: Checking the existing encoding of a file can be hard unless it has a BOM. Generally there is no indicator within a file, you need to know from metadata.

Comment: Please give me reason of downvote.

Comment: Refer this site https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40709064/change-language-of-visual-studio-2017-rc

Comment: @VIGNESHARUNACHALAM I think you're talking about something irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an encoding issue. I had the same issue with **Hebrew** characters. (Arabic and Hebrew are both unsupported in Unicode - we are not so different after all :)

Under the file with the problematic characters, choose from the Visual Studio menu:

**File** > **Save As** -> Then click the down arrow on the Save button and clicking **"Save With Encoding..."**

Then select the UTF-8 value:

[image]

**Note:** This will not auto-correct the corrupted Arabic text, you would have to **rewrite them** and then save your file again.

Comment: But i found some files are fine.without changing encoding

Comment: @SAL What do you mean? If some files are fine this means they are already saved as UTF-8.

Comment: i think **File > Advanced Save Options** not in VS 2017. I see in 2013

Comment: File-> Save As -> then clicking the down arrow on the Save button and clicking "Save With Encoding..." @SAL

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. and this is the issue of locale. Because if the language is non-Unicode then have to select default locale.

**Note** No need to rewrite the page. It will **auto-correct.**
[image]