# How to change VisualStudio 2017 language to English?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I already searched for this problem on the internet. People were suggesting to install language pack. But English is built in language. It was installed by default.
But When I go to
Narzędzia/Opcje/Ustawienia miedzynarodowe
(Tools/Options/Region options)

I have only two options: (Polish, Same as operating system).
So there is no option to select English.

I installed, English in my OS (I think it was by default there). And I switched to English. I see apps in english, my control panel is in english.
But VisualStudio is still in Polish.

Comment: Look at this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40709064/change-language-of-visual-studio-2017-rc

Comment: yeah I did that already, didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figure out that. I had to reinstall OS. Then install Visual Studio 2017 again. Something collided with 17, perhaps previous version 12,13,15. Or maybe it was a problem with OS, because I had Win10 Education version (which is beta version of Win10).

nether less, F***CK Microsoft

Comment: Reinstall the OS to only translate a software ?? Please consider the solution of @ciryatan instead..

Answer (score 14):

1. Open up *Visual Studio Installer*.
2. Under the *downloaded* section, you'll see Visual Studio there.
3. Click on the *modify* button below.
4. Under the *language packages* tab you'll see English there, check the box and download it.
5. Go to Visual Studio itself.
6. **Tools -> Options -> International Settings -> Language -> English**
7. Restart Visual Studio and have fun!

Comment: In Visual Studio 2019 the International Setting option is under **Tools->Options->Environment->International Settings->...**

Answer (score 0):

What I had to do, was make sure the "English" was my default language (ie: top-most language, in the list).

This let the "login screen" pull my actual language (vs the Maoi I use for keyboarding "ō" type letters (aka "macrons")).

Hopefully this helps. ^_^