# WinAPI Hooking CreateFileW in Notepad

Tags: c++, winapi, hook, stack-overflow, detours

I made a DLL which should hook `CreateFileW` from Notepad but however its crashing. After debugging it I found out that its causing a stack overflow in the first line of the `HookedCreateFile` function:

[image: Screenshot]

(its saying that its causing a exception error at the address...)

The callstack at exception point:

[image: Callstack?]

My code:

```
typedef HANDLE(WINAPI * CreateFileFn)(
    LPCWSTR lpFileName,
    DWORD dwDesiredAccess,
    DWORD dwShareMode,
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes,
    DWORD dwCreationDisposition,
    DWORD dwFlagsAndAttributes,
    HANDLE hTemplateFile);

CreateFileFn oCreateFile = (CreateFileFn)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("kernel32.dll"), "CreateFileW");

HANDLE WINAPI HookedCreateFile(
    LPCWSTR lpFileName,
    DWORD dwDesiredAccess,
    DWORD dwShareMode,
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes,
    DWORD dwCreationDisposition,
    DWORD dwFlagsAndAttributes,
    HANDLE hTemplateFile)
{
    //std::cout << "Hello!" << std::endl;

    return oCreateFile(lpFileName, dwDesiredAccess, dwShareMode, lpSecurityAttributes, dwCreationDisposition, dwFlagsAndAttributes, hTemplateFile);
}
```

I am using `DetourFunction` from the Microsoft Detours:

```
DetourFunction((PBYTE)oCreateFile, (PBYTE)HookedCreateFile);
```

Comment: Do not post images of code. Post the actual code as text.

Comment: You didn't provide enough information for us to help you. At least try to explain _how_ you hook it. Also since its stack overflow, you should really look at callstack.

Comment: @Ivan added the code line you probably mean.

Comment: From your original code I can assume you are doing this by changing function prologue insert call to `HookedCreateFile`. What do you think happens when you call the original once again?

Comment: @Ivan Okay so returning the orignal function in the hooked function is wrong? If its wrong what do I return instead of the original Function?

Comment: @logiX I don' know how `DetourFunction` works internally, so I can't say anything. You still barely posted enough code to help you. Definition of `CreateFileFn` is required too - you might be missing `__stdcall` there.

Comment: @logiX: You have to run the *original* first instructions of the function (what they were before you replaced them with a detour) and then jump to an instruction that you haven't overwritten (further into the function).

Comment: If you want others to understand your errors, please [install the English language pack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40709064/1889329) for Visual Studio. And post text instead of images. Virtually every view in Visual Studio allows you to copy text out of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, `DetourFunction()` is old, it has been replaced with `DetourAttach()`. You should update your code to use a new version of the Detours library.  See Microsoft's wiki on [Using Detours](https://github.com/Microsoft/Detours/wiki/Using-Detours).

Second, when you detour a function, you are replacing the first few instructions of the function with a jump into your hook function. `DetourFunction()` returns a **trampoline**, which you MUST use to call the *original* function. The trampoline executes the instructions that were replaced, and then jumps to the remaining unhooked code of the *original* function.

But, your hook is not using the trampoline at all, so every time it calls `oCreateFile`, it ends up calling back into itself, over and over in an endless recursive loop. That is what is causing the stack overflow error, as every call pushes another copy of the input parameters onto the call stack. Eventually, the call stack runs out of available space.

Try this instead:

```
CreateFileFn origCreateFile = (CreateFileFn) GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("kernel32.dll")), "CreateFileW");
CreateFileFn trampCreateFile;

HANDLE WINAPI HookedCreateFile(
    LPCWSTR lpFileName,
    DWORD dwDesiredAccess,
    DWORD dwShareMode,
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes,
    DWORD dwCreationDisposition,
    DWORD dwFlagsAndAttributes,
    HANDLE hTemplateFile)
{
    //std::cout << "Hello!" << std::endl;
    return trampCreateFile(lpFileName, dwDesiredAccess, dwShareMode, lpSecurityAttributes, dwCreationDisposition, dwFlagsAndAttributes, hTemplateFile);
}

...

trampCreateFile = (CreateFileFn) DetourFunction((PBYTE)origCreateFile, (PBYTE)HookedCreateFile);
```